# Asking for password when I open SSRS report from application

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, sql-server-2014

I have created and deployed reports in SQL Server 2014 and also integrated the same in one of my application.

When any user tries to access any report, it asks for user id and password.

Can anyone help me to avoid asking for User id and Password.

I have tried to set authentication from Report Server Configuration Manager

Comment: Have you tried going into the Site Settings and setting security there?

Comment: The report server asks the user's browser for authentication. The browser has to be configured for "Integrated Windows Authentication" and must "trust" the report server URL for this. The way to configure this (on the client) depends on the browser that the user uses.

Comment: I have added server URL in trusted sites. Still it's asking for Server Credential(Windows not SQL)